# Redirect RewriteRule htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product-detail.php?asin=$1 [NC,L]
```

i have the above rerwrite rules

```
http://localhost/fashe-colorlib/B07CNMLF8P
http://localhost/fashe-colorlib/product-detail.php?asin=B07CNMLF8P
```

the above urls are working though i want to get rid of the following url completely.

```
http://localhost/fashe-colorlib/product-detail.php?asin=B07CNMLF8P
```

This is how my link looks like

```
<a href="/fashe-colorlib/product-detail.php?asin=<?php echo $cat_Asin; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/fashe-colorlib/<?php echo $cat_Asin; ?>">
```